# any of this or these?

Tags: grammar, verbs, subjects, agreement

Can you help me correct this sentence? "Whether it's a cup of coffee or tea, our cake goes well with any of THIS or THESE? " this seems a little confusing since ANY is usually used in plural and uncountable nouns.

Comment: *These* makes sense despite the singular choice of *or*: Choose one drink, and only one -- coffee, tea, or milk. Our cake goes well with any and all of these.

Comment: 'Any of ...' requires more than 2 items in count usages, so a rewrite is needed. 'Coffee, tea, cocoa or rooibos ... our cake goes well with any of xxxxxx'. Plural items, so **these**. And 'all' probably sounds more encouraging.

Comment: 'These' agrees with the number of  nouns.  As far as I can think, "any of this" is used with uncountable subjects...  eg - "I will not have any of this nonsense" , or "any of this stuff". On second thought, I would agree with Edwin Asworth above, and by that  logic it should be 'either of these'